# In Spring Boot, how can I enable logging only for certain users?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

To give you some context, we have various microservices and a config server where we store store all the `application.yml` files.

The problem is when some issue happens, we have to temporarily enable logs for every application so that we can trace the activities done by the user. But this creates a hassle as we have to change the log configs.

So we want to enable logging for only certain users (say, when some issue happens and we want to debug) via changing the yml files so we don't have to touch the code or redeploy the application. Basically we are thinking of creating a `application-logging.yml` file for all the microservices and in this when we mention

```
logging:
   users:
      id: 123
      level: warn
```

all the microservices will pick it up and start generating logs only for this user.

How can I implement this in Spring Boot, if its possible?

Comment: For starters, what logging framework are you use using?

Comment: We are using log4j

Answer (score 2):

Put user ID into the thread context then use a [MutableThreadContextMapFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#MutableThreadContextMapFilter).

You can specify values via a JSON file, which log4j polls periodically to pick up changes.